# How to read "lunar orb" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

The following sentence is from the English translation of a 5th century Latin book, at point 863 it says:

> The brightness of the sun encircles the lunar orb and bathes with light the entire part which faces it. These brilliant rays also reach the earth, like an image of light reflected in a mirror. When the moon receives the light in the phase of its first rising, it is obscured from us; and as it draws away from the sun in the west, it begins to grow light.

Now orb has both [meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orb#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20orb,4%20%3A%20eye) of sphere and orbit, How should it be read?

[image]

Comment: Would you say the sun encircles the lunar orbit or sphere?

Comment: Certainly you can. The moon's orbit around the Earth is wholly within the the sphere of the Sun's radiance, as is the Earth's orbit around the Sun. The cited passage is a good (if archaic) description of the difference between sunlight and moonlight, as perceived from Earth.

Comment: @JohnLawler what is your opinion? what is the correct reading? sphere or orbit?

Comment: My opinion about the correct translation of a 5th-century Latin manuscript is no opinion at all. I don't deal with manuscripts or 5th-century Latin.

Comment: Is there a date for this translation?

Comment: @JohnLawler Respect sir/ma'am, I am not asking for translation from Latin to English, but about English reading, should I read it as moon sphere or orbit from English translation?

Comment: @StuartF IT'S TRANSLATE IN 1977

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The translator, William Harris Stahl, is translating *De nuptiis philologiae, et Mercurii* ([[The Marriage of Philology and Mercury]](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Marriage_of_Philology_and_Mercury/EO2ncAAACAAJ?hl=en)) by Martianus Capella. I'll approach this first as a reader of English and then as someone who knows the Latin text.

### The English

An English speaker will tend to hear *orb* as sphere before thinking of *orb* as *orbit*. (Note the "archaic" mark on the definition pertaining to *orbit*; a 20th century author would usually be careful to distinguish *orb* and *orbit*. As a soft form of evidence, do an image search for *orb* and see what you get.) Also, try to imagine light *encircling* something; that only makes sense if *orb* is an object that can be encircled by light. Definition 3 ("a spherical body") would be the usage here.

In other words, "lunar orb" describes the moon as a sphere. In the first sentence, the brightness of the sun encircles the moon and lights its face. In the second sentence, the moon is like a mirror reflecting the light back to the Earth. The third sentence describes the start of a moon phase, receiving sunlight obscured from us at first but growing more light as the moon rises further and further apart from the sun.

### The Latin

Here is the Latin (VIII.863, p. 673, [transcribed from a PDF of the 1836 edition](https://archive.org/details/denuptiisphilolo00martuoft)):

> Circuit enim eius globum undiquesecus Solis nitor, et ei parti, quam totam tunc adspicit, lumen indulget, cuius luminis radii in terras quoque luculentiores perveniunt, ut si quis ex speculo lumine repercusso effigem lucis excipiat.

As a matter of translation, William Harris Stahl closely followed the Latin in the first sentence:

> The brightness of the sun [*Solis nitor*] encircles [*circuit*] the lunar orb [*globum eius* (*eius* is a pronoun referring to the Moon within the passage)].

So this isn't even Latin *orbis*, which could theoretically refer to either a ring or a sphere ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orbis)). *Globum* would be a sphere or, literally, a globe ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/globus#Latin)). Correspondingly, *orb* refers to the round object itself (the moon), not anything elaborate like an orbit.

Comment: I [searched for `orb` with Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=orb&tbm=isch), and I only got orbs (nice-looking spherical items).